# A block must start with a tag name

Tags: include

I have that simple variable in my javascript

`var toLoad = '{% "include _views/reviews.twig" %}';`

and on a page load I get template error that is defined in the title of question.

That variable is defined in template, that includes another template and in that included template is called some 'class' to load `reviews.twig` from our variable defined in parent template.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've got a quote in the wrong place.

This...

```
{% "include _views/reviews.twig" %}
```

should be this...

```
{% include "_views/reviews.twig" %}
```